# How to rotate login screen in elementary os Freya

Tags: elementary-os

I've been attempting to find a solution to this for a few months now but I can't seem to find anything. I have two monitors, one rotated clockwise.  At the login screen the rotated monitor does not rotate the login menu to match. When logged into Elementary the monitor is correctly configured. Is there a way to get the login screen to be rotated as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [arandr](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) programm which export bash script which on executing configure your screens. When you have "the script" for configuration you must execute "script" after the moment the [xinit is executed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc).